# How to run custom shell script file before pre commit hook

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

In my python project, I have pre-commit-config.YAML where I want to create my custom file.

The intention of this file is fail git commit if python lint errors are greater than certain numbers. The following command will be used to count lines

```
pylint api/ | wc -l
```

Can someone please suggest some approach. I am new to the MAC and Python ecosystem?

EDIT
sh file looks like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
a=$(pylint source/ | wc -l)
b=20

errorsCount="$(echo "${a}" | tr -d '[:space:]')"

if [ $errorsCount -gt $b ]
then
    exit 1
fi
```

I tried

```
repos:
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: custom-script-file
      name: custom-script-file
      entry: hooks/pre-commit.sh
      language: script
      types: [python]
      pass_filenames: false
```

But it wouldn't worked.

Comment: `But it wouldn't worked` could you be more specific? How did you test that it doesn't work? Any error output?

Comment: guessing, your "wouldn't worked" is that it's being `Skipped`?  try it with `--all-files` or by setting `always_run: true` (if you want it to always run)

Answer (score 49):

Here's what you could do to use inline bash command as pre-commit hook entry

```
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: pylint-error-count
      name: pylint-error-count
      entry: bash -c 'lines=$(pylint api/ | wc -l) && (( lines > 10)) && exit 1'
      language: system
      types: [python]
      pass_filenames: false
```

You can also write a script and invoke it this way:

```
      entry: path/relavite/to/repo/root/pylint_validator.sh
      language: script
```

NOTE: `wc -l` is not an accurate count of errors.

EDIT: adding more options

```
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: simple-pylint
      name: simple-pylint
      entry: pylint
      args: ["api/"]
      language: system
      types: [python]
      pass_filenames: false

    - id: inline-pylint-with-bash
      name: inline-pylint-with-bash
      entry: bash -c 'lines=$(pylint api/ | wc -l) && (( lines > 10)) && exit 1'
      language: system
      types: [python]
      pass_filenames: false

    - id: custom-script-file
      name: custom-script-file
      entry: relative/path/to/repo/root/check_pylint.sh
      language: script
      types: [python]
      pass_filenames: false
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you let me know it using a pluggable script file? I would be adding more checks. I will verify it and mark it as an answer later.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please again check. Third way did not worked.

Comment: Inline one:
entry: bash -c 'lines=$(pylint api/ | wc -l) && (( lines > 10)) && exit 1'
did not worked.